# Clojure Repl does not run in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clojure

I am a newbie to both clojure and eclipse. I am trying to run clojure unit test cases(in eclipse) in the following way:
1) right click on the file
2) Clojure -> Load file in REPL

This gives a dialog box that says
*Errors exist in required project(s):

Proceed with Launch?*

On clicking "Proceed" nothing happens. There is not even an error.

However, it works fine with other projects, and I get test results.

Eclipse:
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

CounterClockWise 0.35.1.STABLE001

Could you please help me resolve this problem?

Comment: Well, if it's saying there's an error, I'd trust that. I'd work on finding the error first. Run `lein check`. That will find any problems.

Comment: The existing errors which should be better fixed before running something are shown in the [_Problems_ view](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm).